# Python 3 lxml: Error getting attributes from an xml into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, lxml

I am reading an XML to transfer its attributes to other XML file with the same source. However something is wrong in the loop as I am overwriting the first element of the dictionary with the newest one.

The XMl looks like this:

```
<sxml locale="en-US" version="1.0" segtype="sentence" options="eol=unix;" createdby="AP 2.24.1" datatype="regexp" targetlocale="DE">
<family blockId="1" mat="33" type="freeOS" seccion="2" datatype="html" subtype="BSD"><section sectionId="1">
<product>FreeBSD</product>
</section></family>
<family blockId="2" mat="32" type="privative" seccion="3" datatype="html" subtype="commercial"><section sectionId="1">
<product>Windows</product><ws> </ws>
</section><section sectionId="2">
<product>Sistema operativo.</product>
</section></family>
</sxml>
```

And I want to get the attributes: "mat", "seccion", "type" and "subtype".

My code is:

```
from lxml import etree as et
from pathlib import Path
def add_attributes(files_path_str, proc_path_str, attributes):
    """
    Adds the attributes to the frequent files.

    """

    product_path = Path(files_path_str)
    proc_files = Path(unk_path_str).glob('*.sxml')
    dict_notes_src = dict()
    list_src_sxml_files = full_sxml_path.glob('**/*.sxml')

    for sxml_file in list_full_sxml_files:

        xml_parser = et.parse(str(sxml_file))
        root_xml = xml_parser.getroot()
        print(sxml_file)

        dict_notes_src_temp = __generate_notes_product_dict(root_xml,  attributes)
        dict_notes_src = {**dict_notes_src, **dict_notes_src_temp}
    #It is the part where I copy the attributes to the processed files. The bug is not found in this part.
    #The bug is somewhere in the generation of the dictionary
    #for proc_file in list_proc_sxml_files:
    #    xml_parser = et.parse(str(unk_file))
    #    root_unk_xml = xml_parser.getroot()
    #    tree = __add_notes_to_unk(root_unk_xml, dict_notes_src)
    #    tree.write(str(unk_file), encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)

def __generate_notes_product_dict(root_xml, attributes):
    """
    Internal method to process the xml file to get a dictionary product-note.

    """ 

    translatable_elements = root_xml.xpath('family')
    notes_product = dict()

    dict_values = dict()
    for element in translatable_elements:
        product_elements = element.xpath('./section/product')
        list_attrib_values = []
        print(element.tag, element.attrib)
        #satt_note = element.attrib['satt_note']
        # List comprehension fails if there is a segment without an expected attribute.
        #list_attrib_values = [element.attrib[attribute] for attribute in attributes]
        # Checks if there are attributes that does not exist in the Full WordFast file.
        # If that is the case ignores them and adds a None value.
        for attribute in attributes:
            try:
                list_attrib_values.append(element.attrib[attribute])
                print('Reading the attributes. {} : {}'.format(attribute, element.attrib[attribute]))
                logging.debug('__generate_notes_product_dict: Add values of the attributes {}: {}'.format(
                        attribute, element.attrib[attribute]))
            except KeyError:
                list_attrib_values.append(None)
        if len(product_elements) > 0:
            for product_element in product_elements:
            #product_element = element.xpath('./segment/product')[0]
                product_str = str(et.tostring(product_element), 'utf-8')
                # Create the string of the content of the product element.
                product_str = ' '.join(product_str.split())
                if list_attrib_values is not None:
                    if product_str not in notes_product:
                        # Generate a dictionary with the product text as key.
                        #notes_product[product_str] = satt_note
                        print(product_str)
                        for attribute in attributes:
                            try:
                                print(element.tag, element.attrib)
                                dict_values[attribute] = element.attrib[attribute]
                            except KeyError:
                                dict_values[attribute] = None

                        #for attribute, value in zip(attributes, list_attrib_values):
                         #   if value is not None:
                            #    print ('Adding the values {}: {}'.format(attribute,  value))
                            #    dict_values[attribute] = value
                        attrib_product[product_str] = dict_values
    return attrib_product
add_attributes(folder_where_is_stored_xml, folder_where_save_xml,["mat", "seccion", "type", "subtype"]
```

It return a dictionary that all the products have the attributes of the last family.

I've been debugging the code and it looks like the when I running attrib_product[product_str] = dict_values is looping through all the values of the dict_values and stores only the last one.

Any ideas where am I doing wrong? I am not able to see why it is happening.

Comment: The `add_attributes()` function is never called in your code. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have finally found the issue. It was dict_notes_src= dict() that should be inside the first loop instead of out. As that was a temporal variable for every element, never should have been out, so I was storing there more values than the right ones.